# Don't or didn't?

Tags: grammar

Don't worry if you **don't** finish the report.
or Don't worry if you **didn't** finish the report.
which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 2):

If you are telling them about the future then use **don't** and if you are talking about the past then use **didn't**

**Examples:**

Don't worry if you **didn't** finish the assignment which was due yesterday.

Don't worry if you **don't** finish the assignment by tomorrow.